# Bang! New Identity Health

Tags: bang

According to the Bang! High Noon Card "New Identity":

> At the beginning of their turn, each player looks at the character he is using to keep track of his life points. He may switch to the new identity for the rest of the game, **starting with 2 life points**.

Does this mean that if you switch to the new identity, you start off with 2 health and that is the maximum for that identity? Or can you use beer/whiskey/etc. to increase your new identity's health up to the maximum on the character card?

Comment: Its the High Noon expansion not High Moon.

Comment: consider it fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that means when you switch to the other character your health is set at 2 points and on your turn you can gain the missing health back. Which means that if you are switching to a character that has 4 bullets normally you can then play a whiskey to go back up to 4 bullets in health. Also if you are the sheriff in this game you could follow up with a beer and be back up to 5 health with the +1 health bonus for being sheriff.

What the setting to two life does is impose a penalty for switching if you are above 2 live or a small bonus for switching if you are at 1 life.